# Need advice on how to set up live video streaming to web/mobile devices

Tags: flash, video-streaming, android, video

I have a bunch of live udp video streams that currently are viewed by set top boxes in my network. I would like to pick this video up (I can do this with vlc now) and stream it out to other non-STB endpoints (webpage or a phone/tablet of some sort).

Right now I am able to pick up the udp stream with vlc and convert it to an http stream on port 8080 of my vlc box. Then I can use the vlc client to pick up and watch that video stream.

This is where I'm not sure where to go with it. I really doubt I would want everyone who is watching the video to make a connection back to my vlc server that is doing the encoding, so how do I distribute this live video to the people who want to see it?

Comment: What kind of requirements do you have?  Does your stream need to be private?  Have you consider just using some service like ustream which already has clients on portable devices?

Comment: I am really just trying to put together a proof of concept right now. In the end, the streams will need to be private at some point, probably behind a username/password built into the app I intend to build.

Answer (score 0):

Setup VLC to convert your UDP streams into a web-compatible format such as Apple's HTTP live streaming. You may have to ask VLC to deposit the streams into a WebDAV-enabled server such as Apache. You can then point your users at Apache itself, or front it with a web accelerator such as Varnish if you are expecting a large audience.

You might consider a live transcoding appliance such as Envivio 4Caster or Harmonic ProStream 4000 to replace VLC.

Hope this helps.